# AngularJs Factory Type:Error request.then(...) error is not a function

Tags: angularjs

My `service` code:

```
application.factory('Http', function($http) {
    var base_url = "Angular_Database/server.php";
    return {
        post: function(form_data) {
            var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: base_url,
                data: form_data
            });
            return request;
        },

        send: function(request, callback) {
            request.then(function(response) {
                callback(response);
            }).error(function(Object) {
                alert(Object.data);
            });
        }
    }
})
```

here, The problem is in the `.then()`.

My `console` says:

> Type:Error request.then(...) error is not a function

Comment: error function has already been deprecated since angular `1.5.X`, use 2nd function `.then` as `errorCallback`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `error()` function in the `HttpPromise` object starting from `Angular 1.5.X` (Based on comment). You need to use `catch()` function instead of it.

```
request.then(function(response) {
          callback(response);
        }).catch(function(Object) {
               alert(Object.data);
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also could be:

```
    request.then(function(response) {
       callback(response);
    }, function(error){
       alert(error.data);
    })
```